# Zeta function of the Grassmanian

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I want to find the Hasse–Weil zeta function on the Grassmanian G(n, k), by using the definition in http://www.math.ru.nl/~jcommelin/files/localfactorsSerre.pdf, ie $$Z(T)=\prod_{m=0}^{m=2r}P_{l,m}(T)$$ 
where the polynomial $P_{l,m}(T)$ is given by
$$P_{l,m}(T)=det(I-T\pi_{l,m})$$

But I'm not very comfortable with cohomology, could you show me how to calculate the polynomials and thus the function?

Thanks in advance!

ps
I'm aware of the method of counting the points of the space, and then using $Z(T)=exp(\sum N_{r}\frac{T^{r}}{r})$, but I'd like to see how to do it using the other method.

Comment: $\pi_{\ell,m}$ is the Frobenius endormorphism of $\ell$-adic $m$-th cohomology (a  $\Bbb{Q}_\ell$ vector space), one of the main point is to show its characteristic polynomial is in $\Bbb{Q}[T] \subset \Bbb{Q}_\ell[T]$ (because it is an isogeny of some abelian variety over a number field)

Comment: While commenting on a question or an answer, the user who has posted it automatically gets notified but the other users who have also made a comment there do not. In order that the user other than the OP gets notified one must write @[name of the user without the square bracktes]. I assumed you are new here and hence the reason for my comment.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this link : http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/SeminarOnCohomology/GrassmannVarieties%20.pdf

Comment: @random123 Thanks, but I'm trying to compute the function without resorting to the formula concerning the number of points of the space, thanks a lot though!

Comment: @reuns Thanks, but I don't quite know how to find it, nor $det(I-T \pi), which is why I'm asking for help. Thanks for any advice!